# How to store multiple key values in an Array on one field

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a football team model as seen here

```
type Team @model
  {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    faId: ID!
    seasonID: ID!
    seasons: [seasonID] @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
  }
```

The team will play in multiple seasons. I would like to store the data in a array

```
seasonID: [ID]!
```

Then when fetching the data, I can return all the seasons the Team was a part of.

Is this possible with Dynamodb. When I try to say it this way it says:

```
InvalidDirectiveError: All fields provided to an @connection must be non-null scalar or enum fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidDirectiveError: All fields provided to an @connection must be non-null scalar or enum fields.` means that the part where you have `[seasonID]` should not be any of the typs `ID`, `String`, `Int` etc as shown & described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html)

The connection for cardinality One-To-Many `1..*` you are trying to do there would be achieved by creating a separate model called `Season`. eg:

```
# Separate model for Season
type Season @model{
   id: ID!
   name: String!
}
 
type Team @model
{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    faId: ID!
    seasonID: ID!
    seasons: [Season] @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
}
```

You can see a example of more you can do [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/connection)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. The seasonID is still just a single field expecting an ID when attempting to create a team.